# Copying Parent model attribute to all of its children with same attribute in mysql or Rails as single Query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I know we need to use the following sudo code in case of Rails

```
Parent.all.each do |parent|
    parent.childrens.update_all(:price => parent.price)
end
```

But I have like 5 Million Parent records and I know this would take a lot of time.

Is there a easy way to do the above through Rails or MySQL the fastest way (in a single query)

Comment: Try `Child.update_all( 'price=(SELECT price FROM parents WHERE parents.id=children.parent_id)' )`. Hint: you can add table schemes and there will be a chance to get answer from Mysql guru.

Answer (score 0):

```
Parent.includes(:childrens).find_in_batches.find_in_batches do |group|
  sleep(50)
  group.each { |parent| parent.childrens.update_all(price: parent.price) }
end
```

This is the best you can come up with rails atleast..it will avoid `n+1` also, since the records are huge, [`find_in_batches`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html) will help you, otherwise there is a possibility that your db/dyno gets locked..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ActiveRecord callback functionality to achieve this.

Example code would look like this:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :denormalize
  has_many :children

  private

  def denormalize
    children.update_all(price: price)
  end
end
```

This will ensure that, whenever a parent object is modified the child will also be updated.

Comment: This is ok for the future records and updates but I am looking for a solution for all the existing 5M records

Comment: @Peru, Then you may have to use Farhan's solution with some extra parameters like find_in_batches(:batch_size => 100)